# chrome extension js not showing alarm or notifications

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications, alarm

I was recently trying to learn about chrome extension and was trying to show some simple alert, alarm, notification upon a button click.

alert is working for a button click but it seems i can not make it work to trigger alarm or display notification in chrome extensions. No error is being thrown either in service worker dev tool.

Here are the codes. Codes are simple and should work. But i dont know why i am not seeing anything in the chrome. I am fairly new here. any help is appreciated.

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Alarm Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "alarms",
    "notifications"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "icon16.png",
      "48": "icon48.png",
      "128": "icon128.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Alarm Extension</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="triggerAlarm">Trigger Alarm</button>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  document.getElementById("triggerAlarm").addEventListener("click", function () {
    chrome.alarms.create({ delayInMinutes: 1 });
    alert("Alarm set for 1 minute from now!");
  });
});
```

background.js

```
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function (alarm) {
    chrome.notifications.create({
      type: "basic",
      title: "Alarm Triggered",
      message: "Your alarm has been triggered!",
      iconUrl: "icon128.png"
    });
  });
```

For deployment i am going here chrome://extensions/, enabled `developer mood` and `load unpacked`

Can anyone guide what i am doing wrong?

How can i see the trigger alarm or notification in chrome?

PS : Chrome is updated to the latest version. Tried uninstalling installing again. no result :(

Comment: Assuming there are no errors in chrome://extensions for your extension, the code is correct, so it may be a bug in Chrome. Try uninstalling the extension, restart the browser, and install it again.

Comment: i tried that -_-
put a debug log in the background.js
i can see log in dev tool -_-

but no error no alarm not notifs :(

Comment: Maybe it'sa  problem with showing any notifications in Chrome. See if an online demo for notifications work. Also see if notifications are allowed in the UI that opens after clicking `Site settings` in the details of your extension inside chrome://extensions page.